# Javascript Regex allow comma in amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I have **Regex** expression which allow user to enter amount with `decimal or without decimal`. I am facing issue when there is `comma(,)` in amount. I want to allow `comma(,)` in amount.

Here is my Regex

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^\\$?(?=.*[1-9])(?:[1-9]\\d*\\.?|0?\\.)\\d*$")
```

The above expression works with following amounts

```
123
1.232
112.2
$12.0
$0.1
```

It fails with following

```
$42,529.41
$4,529.41
```

How can I allow comma in amount? Amount must be greater then zero.

Comment: did you want to match `123,`?

Comment: How can above expression match `123,`?it has no `,`

Comment: @vks See my edit I was separated it with `,`

Comment: Why was this tagged C# orginally? If it is something you are using then there is a much better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\\$?(?=.*[1-9])(?:[1-9]\\d*,?\\d*[.]?|0?[.])\\d*$

                            ^^  ^^
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nD5jY4/1

Answer (score 1):

Use  a pattern to allow comma in the integer part and make it to repeat zero or more times. Add a negative lookahead to not to match `0` or `0.0`, `00`, etc

```
var regexp = /^\$?(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$/m;
```

OR

```
^(?=.*?[1-9])\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mV9vS2/2)

Comment: This looks like a slightly more sane solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: you mean the second one? His regex fails to match `00.001`

Comment: Both solutions takes into account that there can be more than 1 comma - which the solution by vks lacks, and it can be slightly modified to force thousand separator (3 digits).